# Add CSS styles from Unify Template to Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Unify template, to not write a great amount of css code. But I have problems adapting the template to Ruby. I transfer all the assets from Unify to /Assets/Images /javascript and /stylesheets but finally my project seems visually like shit. I use:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>


<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 

    true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

But I can't achieve a good view of my project. How I have to do to import all the assets to my project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do it that way you will have to make sure you require the stylesheet in your application.css file to make sure they are loaded when you call that in your application.html.erb file. Also, make sure the theme doesnt have any dependencies that need to be loaded before it, such as bootstrap or jquery. Inspect the page and see if you are getting any js errors assuming there is js that comes with the template, you will need to require the js files in your application.js.

Comment: I think the easier way is to add all the template asset's files at the public folder of ruby app. I know that's not the better way, but it works... There are a great amount of files depending one each others, so it's so difficult to make it works from the stylesheets folder on ruby app. Thank you!